# What is the Visual Studio(2017) shortcut to rename a bookmark?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, shortcut, hotkeys

I want to know if there is a default shortcut to rename a bookmark in Visual Studio(2017) or what the equivalent command is to manually create the shortcut.

I was looking a command like **Edit.BookmarkRename**.

Answer (score 2):

In the Bookmarks tool window, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to rename the selected bookmark.

Comment: This opens the Object Browser and i do have a bookmark selected. @SergeyVlasov

Comment: @Noahp Looks like F2 is assigned to View.ObjectBrowser command on your machine. You can assign a different shortcut to the View.EditLabel command that will let you rename a bookmark.